# With Android Room, do I need to add setter and getter for nested object?

Tags: java, android, android-room

In the code below, class `Address` is nested in Entity `User`. I wonder if all the attributes of `Address` are `private`, do we need `getter` and `setter` for each of the field in `Address`? Notice there is a `List<String>`, so I'm not sure if `Room` will work well with `@TypeConverter` in this case.

```
public class Address {
    public String street;
    public String state;
    public List<String> city;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "post_code")
    public int postCode;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    public String firstName;

    @Embedded
    public Address address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add getter/setters with `@Ignore` annotation and the converter will ignore these methods.

```
 @Ignore 
 public List<String> getCity() {
     return city;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer here
[Create the entity](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3)